# How to continue evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2x^n}{n!}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

To evaluate this I tried to write it in the form of $\sum_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^m}{m!}=e^x$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^2x^n}{n!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)x^n}{(n-1)!}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}=\underbrace{x^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-2}}{(n-2)!}}_{f_1(x)}+\underbrace{x\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-1}}{(n-1)!}}_{f_2(x)}$$

We have $f_2(x)=xe^x$.

But:

$$f_1(x)=x^2\times\left(\frac{x^{-1}}{\color{red}{(-1)!}}+e^x\right)$$

It seems I am very close to get the answer but I don't know how to get rid of "$(-1)!$". Is there any way to continue or fix that?

Comment: Isolate the case $n=1$ from $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(n-1)x^n}{(n-1)!}$.

Comment: Another approach: if $D = x {d \over dx}$, your sum is $D^2 \exp x$.

Comment: Well extending the factorials to the Gamma funtion: $\frac{1}{(-1)!}= 0$.

Comment: @Mourad Isn't $n!$ for $n<0$ undefined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As regards $f_1$, note that $(n-1)x^{n}$ is identically zero
for $n=1$ and therefore
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)x^{n}}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{(n-1)x^{n}}{(n-1)!}=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{(n-2)!}=x^2\sum_{m=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{m}}{m!}=x^2e^x$$
where $m=n-2$.

Comment: Thank you, I got it. But I think it was far from mind. we normally cancel out $(n-1)$ in fraction without thinking about the interval of summation. But here we fixed interval first then canceling out so hard to recognize.

Answer (score 1):

You need reindexing before it becomes problematic, I put the equal sign:

- in red when a re-indexation occurs
- in blue when initial index is shifted

$S=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^2x^n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{nx^n}{(n-1)!}\color{red}{=}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)x^{n+1}}{n!}=\underbrace{\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{nx^{n+1}}{n!}}_{S_1}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n!}$

Notice that in $S_1$ you cannot simplifiy by $n$ in the case $n=0$, but since the first term is zero the sum is unchanged if we start at summing from $n=1$.

$S_1=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{nx^{n+1}}{n!}\color{blue}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{nx^{n+1}}{n!}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{(n-1)!}\color{red}{=}\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{n!}$

Finally what you got is

$$S=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n+1}}{n!}+\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^{n+2}}{n!}=x\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}+x^2\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^n}{n!}=xe^x+x^2e^x$$